# Linear regression: b1 has the minimum variance among all unbiased linear estimators of beta1

Tags: regression

There is a proof provided in *Applied Linear Regression Models (1983)* by **Kutner et al.** (Page 64), which is quite clear and easy to understand, except one point, namely, it assumes that $\sum k_i d_i = 0$, from the "restrictions on $k_i$ and $c_i$", without expounding on what restrictions these are. Could anyone please explain? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in terms of $k_{i}$ and $c_{i}$

$\sum k_{i}d_{i} = \sum k_{i}(c_{i} - k_{i}) = \sum k_{i}c_{i} - \sum k_{i}k_{i}$

Now $k_{i}$ is the $i^{th}$ coefficient from the least squares estimator, which we know the form of. Turns out with some algebra,

$k_{i} = \frac{(x_{i} - \bar{x})}{\sum(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}}$

plugging this in, and using the fact that $\sum x_{i}c_{i} = 1$ and $\sum c_{i} = 0$

$\sum k_{i}c_{i} = \frac{\sum x_{i}c_{i}}{\sum(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}} - \frac{\sum \bar{x}c_{i}}{\sum (x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}} = \frac{1}{\sum(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}}$

and

$\sum k_{i}^2 = \frac{\sum (x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}}{(\sum (x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2})^{2}} = \frac{1}{\sum (x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}}$

The difference between these two terms is 0.

Comment: Wow, I would like to up vote 10 times for you! Thanks!